Как на существующий сайт поставить админку?
у меня есть сверстаный сайт на reactjs, мне нужно к нему подключить админку, чтобы заказчик мог менять контент на странице. Никак не могу найти ответа как это сделать. Никогда с админками не работал. Как можно это сделать, что нужно?

"Подключить админку" - нет такого для рукописных сайтов. Тут надо вручную написать все это, учитывая реалии вашего сайта.
